# I am trying to display data from grid into Modal using linq and I get an error telling me "Enumeration yielded no results"

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

These filter values should return some data in the row base on data-keys/ID but it just doesn't work, so I'm guessing my query is wrong, can you help please.

```
IEnumerable <DataRow> query = from i in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                     where i.Field<int>("ID").Equals(data)
                                     select i;
        DataTable detailTable = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
        PreViewData.DataSource = detailTable;
        PreViewData.DataBind();
```

Comment: What happens when you step through the code?  What is in i and data?

Comment: When I step through the code I get the role ID which is data and I want to use that to retrieve all that records on the row base on that ID

Comment: The code you show doesn't do anything. Where is `query` actually executed? Also, which type is `data`? Using `Equals` is deceptive because it allows type inequality.

Comment: The ID may be a string with leading zeroes so you may not be matching.

Comment: @GertArnold:
IEnumerable <DataRow> query = from i in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                         where i.Field<int>("ID").Equals(data)
                                         select i;
            DataTable detailTable = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
            PreviewData.DataSource = detailTable;
            PreviewData.DataBind();